# Copying Folder with SHFileOperation error

Tags: c++

I am trying to use SHFileOperation to copy the files in a folder (only files, no recursion) to a sub-folder. I have the following piece of code which is failing, SHFileOperation returns 1223 and I get a window with only a Cancel button saying:

> "The destination folder is a subfolder of the source folder."

```
bool CopyFolder(std::string source, std::string destination)
{
            SHFILEOPSTRUCTA sf;

            source.append(1, '\0');
            destination.append(1, '\0');

            sf.hwnd = GetDesktopWindow(); //Temporary just so I can see any messages
            sf.pFrom = source.c_str();
            sf.pTo = destination.c_str();
            sf.wFunc = FO_COPY;
            sf.fFlags = FOF_NORECURSION | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_SILENT;

            int result = SHFileOperation(&sf);

            if (result == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            std::cout << "Error: " << result << std::endl;

            return false;
}
```

Now if I comment the line where I am setting the fFlags, it runs successfully and all the files/folders are copied to the sub-folder. Does anyone know that are the default flags it uses when you don't set them, or how can I avoid this error while setting the flags I want i.e. copy files only?

Comment: I guess (just guessing) the default flags is "indeterminate" because `sf` is default-initialized.

Comment: Why are you null terminating your strings and then calling `c_str()`?

Comment: The error relates to `ERROR_CANCELLED` which means the operation was cancelled?

Comment: Many Windows structs require zero-initialization before use.  You did not do that with your declaration of `sf`.

Comment: Not an effort at solving the current problem - however, did you see that the function was replaced back about 10 years ago with a COM interface? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JonnyHenly If I don't null terminate the strings I get ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, and without c_str() it will not compile with error "cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'PCZZSTR'. How do you suggest doing it?

Comment: @SeverusSnape *If I don't null terminate the strings I get ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND* -- The `c_str()` gives you a null-terminated string, so what is the reason to null-terminate something that is already going to be null-terminated?  Second, did you look at my comment?  You should zero-initialize the struct and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: @SeverusSnape -- For example, `ZeroMemory(sf, 0, sizeof(sf));` or `SHFILEOPSTRUCTA sf = {};` before you start setting individual members.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added the initialization of the struct and getting the same result. About the null termination, that's odd though because if I don't add the '\0' and use c_str() alone I still get the file not found error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah, looking at the link posted by enhzflep it says, "SHFileOperation required path and destination strings to terminate in two null characters rather than the standard single null character...", so I guess that explains why I need to null terminate the string.

Comment: My comment on `ZeroMemory` should be `ZeroMemory(&sf, 0, sizeof(sf));` -- forgot the `&`.

Comment: So far I managed to solve this by adding \*.* at the end of the source path and also added FOF_FILESONLY to the flags. Still would love to know why I get that error when setting the flags, but it works when I don't set any flags!